# tick mark separation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles, pgf-core

My graphs have two ticks on the x-axis. I'd like to have 3 graphs across a page and include y-axis labels. Right now that wont fit. Is it possible to move the x-tick marks closer together so the graphs aren't as wide?

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{figure}[tbp]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.26\linewidth}
\caption{Average Playback Version}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[
%x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
xlabel=Available Bandwidth (Mbps),
xtick={0, 1},
xticklabels={Early, Late},
enlarge x limits=0.15,
enlarge y limits=upper,
legend style={at={(0.5,1.0)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar,
bar width=5pt,
ymin=0,
]
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,1.1666666666666667) (1,5)};
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,2.8333333333333335) (1,5)};
\legend{0,1,2,3,4}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.26\linewidth}
\caption{Playback Smoothness}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[
%x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
xlabel=Available Bandwidth (Mbps),
xtick={0, 1},
xticklabels={Early, Late},
enlarge x limits=0.15,
enlarge y limits=upper,
legend style={at={(0.5,1.0)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar,
bar width=5pt,
ymin=0,
]
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,0.4289845892077917) (1,1)};
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,0.3173238794109962) (1,1)};
\legend{0,1,2,3,4}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.26\linewidth}
\caption{Prefetching Overhead}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[
%x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
xlabel=Available Bandwidth (Mbps),
xtick={0, 1},
xticklabels={Early, Late},
enlarge x limits=0.15,
enlarge y limits=upper,
legend style={at={(0.5,1.0)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar,
bar width=5pt,
ymin=0,
]
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,0) (1,0.01747354295543597)};
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,0) (1,0.025513165391867983)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{iPad: Long-Term Decreases 4 Mbps - 0.5 Mbps}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `x` option of the `axis` environment, you can give a dimension that is used as unit.
Here writing something like

```
\begin{axis}[
%x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
x=2cm,
enlarge x limits=0.5,
xlabel=Available Bandwidth (Mbps),
xtick={0, 1},
xticklabels={Early, Late},
enlarge y limits=upper,
legend style={at={(0.5,1.0)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar,
bar width=5pt,
ymin=0,
]
```

Gives a more balanced result.

If you want to set these dimensions globally you may use

```
\pgfplotsset{width={<dimension>}, height={<dimension>}}
```